# GDB 7.6 STL pretty print with gcc-4.8 and mac os 10.9

Tags: macos, gcc, stl, gdb, pretty-print

I'm struggling to get the pretty prints as described [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) in gdb working on my mac. I downloaded the latest gdb through macports and using `gcc-4.8`.
I loaded the `~/.gdbinit` file and the printers are registered, but whenever I call 
`print myVector` it gives me the raw output. 
Any suggestions what I could do? Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: try @Marco answer it's work !

Answer (score 3):

To have pretty printer with libc++ (new library used in Clang++/LLVM) use this new pretty printer:

https://github.com/koutheir/libcxx-pretty-printers

The .gdbinit is almost the same ([see sample](https://github.com/koutheir/libcxx-pretty-printers/blob/master/src/gdbinit))

I've just tried with Eclipse Luna on OS X 10.10 and it works.

Comment: I try on my mac os x 10.10.3 it's work , GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1,g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions what I could do?

You can try to register pretty printers directly from gdb command line, bypassing `.gdbinit` file to narrow down the problem:

```
ks@ks-comp:~$ gdb -n
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) python
>import sys
>sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ks/stlPrettyPrinter')
>from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
>register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
>end
(gdb)
```

Note, that I've checked out pretty printers in `/home/ks/stlPrettyPrinter` folder:

```
ks@ks-comp:~$ ls -a /home/ks/stlPrettyPrinter
.  ..  hook.in  index.html  libstdcxx  Makefile.am  Makefile.in  patch.txt  .svn
ks@ks-comp:~$
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried it and I get no complaints but still get the following output: <\br> `(gdb) p v
$1 = {<_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >> = {
    _M_impl = {<allocator<double>> = {<new_allocator<double>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x1004000a0,
      _M_finish = 0x1004000f0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x1004000f0}}, <No data fields>}` . I compiled the code with g++-4.8 -g -std=c++11 main.cpp. I new to gdb and really don't know how to approach the problem:/

Answer (score 0):

- If you're using the STL implementation in `libc++` (the default with `clang`), GDB won't know how to pretty print the STL containers
- Switch to using GNU `libstdc++`, and STL pretty printing in `gdb` should work.
- STL pretty printers are implemented as Python programs that know about the implementation details of the STL containers and are maintained along with the STL implementations.
- `libc++` does not ship STL pretty printers that confirm to the [GDB Python pretty printer API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html#Pretty-Printing)

Since you got your `gcc-4.8` from MacPorts and [MacPorts: Using the Right Compiler](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/UsingTheRightCompiler) claims that `gcc-*` defaults to `libstdc++` you should just avoid passing the `-stdlib=` option when using gcc.

Comment: Thank you it works with clang++ and passing -stdlib=libstdc++! But do you any chance know how to pass it through g++-4.8? It doesn' recognize the flag -stdlib=libstdc++. I'm usually passing -std=c++11 to get c++11-features.

Comment: @user3428018, did you get your `gcc-4.8` through macports as well?

Comment: yes I did and I have to use it because of the openmp-support