# mac pretty print gdb

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and not able to get gdb to pretty print containers or strings.  I followed the instructions here [GDB 7.6 STL pretty print with gcc-4.8 and mac os 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449829/gdb-7-6-stl-pretty-print-with-gcc-4-8-and-mac-os-10-9), cloned the gdb pretty printers and added the path to .gdbinit.  However gdb still won't pretty print.  I added the pretty printers after starting gdb to make sure they were registered

```
(gdb) python
>import sys
>sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/liamadams/Documents/gdb/python')
>from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
>register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
>end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Users/liamadams/Documents/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 1739, in register_libstdcxx_printers
    gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(obj, libstdcxx_printer)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.0.1/share/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py", line 152, in register_pretty_printer
    printer.name)
RuntimeError: pretty-printer already registered: libstdc++-v6
```

gdb is registering the pretty printers, I'm running gcc 8.2.0 and gdb 8.0.1.  The pretty printer registered is c++-v6, should it be v8? I cloned this repo to get the pretty printers `svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python`

I built my code using `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/g++-8 -static-libstdc++ -g -o a.out b.o c.o -pthread`

Here is the gdb output when trying to print a string

```
(gdb) p currentItem
$1 = {static npos = <optimized out>, 
  _M_dataplus = {<allocator<char>> = {<new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x7ffeefbff900 "mining"}, _M_string_length = 6, {
    _M_local_buf = "mining\000\000\v\000\000\000\000\000\000", 
    _M_allocated_capacity = 113723912907117}}

(gdb) whatis currentItem
type = string
```

Comment: Are you *building* your program with GCC? The GCC prettyprinters will not work for code compiled with Clang / `libc++`. The `-v6` corresponds to the version of `libstdc++`, and is correct.

Comment: I'm using this command to compile `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/g++-8 -std=c++17 -g -o a.out b.o c.o`. I give the full path to g++ to make sure clang++ doesn't get used.  It may still be using libc++ though

Comment: I tried using the `-static-libstdc++` option when building and it still won't pretty print.  I updated the question with the full command

Comment: Can you show the output when trying to print a string or a vector? The error you show comes from trying to re-register printers for `libstdc++-v6` a second time (don't do *that*).

Comment: Updated, I want to use gdb instead of lldb because it works with Visual Studio Code

Comment: Hopefully last clarifying question: what does `whatis currentItem` say?

Comment: type=string, updated the output above

Comment: I would try putting some `print`s into .py files to check which functions are actually get called by GDB.

Comment: I'm just going to use Xcode and lldb for debugging

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling with `-gdwarf-3` instead of simply `-g`. According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html, GCC defaults to DWARF version 2 on macOS, and explicitely switching to DWARF version 3 makes the symbols correctly appear in the `std::` namespace (I don't yet understand why). So you would not need to patch the pretty printers as [Yongwei Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816999/yongwei-wu) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug. A hack solution is provided in this Stack Overflow question:

[Bug in gdb libstdc++ pretty-printers with gcc 8 installed from macports (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792439/bug-in-gdb-libstdc-pretty-printers-with-gcc-8-installed-from-macports-macos)

Copying from that question, you need to modify the pretty-printer code:

```
--- python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py.old 2018-10-13 13:57:11.000000000 +0300
+++ python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py 2018-10-13 14:35:55.000000000 +0300
@@ -1306,2 +1306,4 @@
     def add(self, name, function):
+        if (name.startswith('std::')):
+            self.add(name[5:], function)
         # A small sanity check.
```